# What do these commands mean and do?

Tags: linux, command, ls

What do these commands mean and do? "ls > l" and "ls >> l". I have tried them, but it seems as if they do the same thing - create a file named "l".

Comment: Try running each twice.

Comment: ">" send your output to a file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ls > l
```

It create the file and write the output of ls into it.

```
ls >> l
```

But this command append the data to existing file if it exist else it does same as above mentioned .

Answer (score 2):

```
ls > l
```

It redirects to file. It creates the file and overwrites whatever is written in it.

```
ls >> l
```

It redirects and append stdout to file.

Answer (score 1):

This commands list a directory.

The first creates a new file every time it runs and write the output to the file.
the second appends the output of ls to the existing file.